# How to select a polygon feature on mapservice?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I manage to publish a mapservice with lots of polygon.

I wish to select a polygon and see its attributes.

May I know how to I perform that with javascript API? There doesn't seems to be a straight forward solution on their sample page.

Comment: You are using ArcGisDyanamic service or feature service?If you are using feature service then you can refer this examples
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/widget_formatInfoWindow.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/popup_sidepanel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the identify task samples: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/#search/IdentifyTask

Here is the link to the api for the identify task: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/identifytask.html